# Create ACK for INVITE

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I would like to know, how I can send ACK after I send INVITE and receive SIP 200 OK for INVITE.

Right now i have the following code to create ACK which is part of ProcessInviteResponse()

```
else if(statusCode == 200){
            try {
                System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().toString());

                response = (Response) responseReceivedEvent.getResponse();
                tid = responseReceivedEvent.getClientTransaction();
                CSeqHeader cseq = (CSeqHeader) response.getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);     
                Dialog dialog = responseReceivedEvent.getDialog();

                if (tid == null) {
                    // RFC3261: MUST respond to every 2xx
                    if (ackRequest!=null && dialog!=null) {
                        System.out.println("re-sending ACK");
                        dialog.sendAck(ackRequest);
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.OK) {
                    dialog = tid.getDialog();
                    System.out.println("Dialog after 200 OK  " + dialog);
                    System.out.println("Dialog State after 200 OK  " + dialog.getState());
                    ackRequest = dialog.createAck(cseq.getSeqNumber() );
                    System.out.println("Sending ACK");
                    dialog.sendAck(ackRequest);
                    System.out.println(ackRequest.toString());
                }

             // Send a Re INVITE
                try {
                    if (reInviteCount == 0) {
//                      logger.info("Sending RE-INVITE");
                        this.functions.sendReInvite();
                         reInviteCount++;
                    } else {
                    this.okReceived = true;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                }



                }
             catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

And I call the ProcessInviteResponse() in ProcessResponse()

```
public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int statusCode = responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode();
        String currentResponse = responseEvent.getResponse().getReasonPhrase();
//      System.out.println("-----------StatusCode:"+ statusCode+"----------------------------");
//      System.out.println("-----------currentREsponse:"+ currentResponse+"----------------------------");
        CSeqHeader cseqtemp = (CSeqHeader) responseEvent.getResponse().getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);          
//      System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse().toString());

        System.out.println("................cseq" + cseqtemp);
        if(cseqtemp.getMethod().equals(Request.REGISTER)){
            processRegisterResponse(responseEvent);
        }else if(cseqtemp.getMethod().equals(Request.INVITE)){

            countInviteResponse ++;
            System.out.println(".....countInviteResponse: "+ countInviteResponse+" ......" );

            if(countInviteResponse == 6){
                System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse());
//              functions.cancel(responseEvent.getResponse());
            }
            try {
                processInviteResponse(responseEvent);
            } catch (SipException | InvalidArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("-------------------Status Code: "+ statusCode+" ----------------------");
            System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse().toString());
        }

    }
```

The dialog is always null and also when I am running the code in Debug mode I see that it reached till
    System.out.println("Dialog after 200 OK  " + dialog);

And after this step it jumps back to the ProcessResponse function

Response:

```
REGISTER sip:sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: f8196fa8aac36be3f4912bafd5562106@localIP
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:username@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-df31c0eec62e6cd957c31283f9d6a936
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>
Content-Length: 0

................cseqCSeq: 1 REGISTER

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-df31c0eec62e6cd957c31283f9d6a936;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=as7ec424a2
Call-ID: f8196fa8aac36be3f4912bafd5562106@localIP
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="34c49d2e"
Content-Length: 0


REGISTER sip:sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: f8196fa8aac36be3f4912bafd5562106@localIP
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:username@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-007bf950de8b30b3fd51e37eafef51a7
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="34c49d2e",uri="sip:sipIP",algorithm=MD5,response="a097cb1e92a6414effc80be476858b2b"
Content-Length: 0


................cseqCSeq: 2 REGISTER

---------------------------Registered: 200--------------------

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-007bf950de8b30b3fd51e37eafef51a7;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=as7ec424a2
Call-ID: f8196fa8aac36be3f4912bafd5562106@localIP
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Expires: 240
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>;expires=240
Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 12:00:07 GMT
Content-Length: 0


REtry INVITE: true
Dialog: createdgov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPDialog@73e0a64c
INVITE sip:86940160@sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 3 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-3c9ab4c15d6a1e8e4c7f22dcc49f0751
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="34c49d2e",uri="sip:sipIP",algorithm=MD5,response="a097cb1e92a6414effc80be476858b2b"
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 3 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 1 ......
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-3c9ab4c15d6a1e8e4c7f22dcc49f0751;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as1c4d69f2
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 3 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="5c1b847c"
Content-Length: 0


------------------Invite 401--------------------

/nINVITE sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 4 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-97013b6016ecd330f834755274cd3361
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="5c1b847c",uri="sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP",response="2d3b46672628d25d0200db9cdcfae0d0",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
******************* Transaction Terminated *****************
Client Transaction:null
Server Transaction:null


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request NOTIFYreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
******************* Transaction Terminated *****************
Client Transaction:null
Server Transaction:null
******************* Transaction Terminated *****************
Client Transaction:gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPDialog@73e0a64c
Server Transaction:null


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 4 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 2 ......
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-97013b6016ecd330f834755274cd3361;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as2b699877
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 4 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="543dee4d"
Content-Length: 0


------------------Invite 401--------------------

/nINVITE sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 5 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-54f581433c4b8c44b094769754dc91b8
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="543dee4d",uri="sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP",response="75fc779e7f4725652796c8065ee71bee",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 5 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 3 ......
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-54f581433c4b8c44b094769754dc91b8;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as7cd7e570
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 5 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="6e84cf0d"
Content-Length: 0


------------------Invite 401--------------------

/nINVITE sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:53412;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="6e84cf0d",uri="sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP",response="8d5f2f25b1394f2fab851b30d12f7391",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 4 ......
------------------- Status Code: 100--------------------------
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Length: 0


................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 5 ......
------------------- Status Code: 183--------------------------
SIP/2.0 183 Session Progress
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731368999 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv



Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 6 ......
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

Dialog after 200 OK  null
................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 7 ......
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

Dialog after 200 OK  null
................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 8 ......
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

Dialog after 200 OK  null
******************* Transaction Terminated *****************
Client Transaction:null
Server Transaction:null
................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 9 ......
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 10 ......
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

................cseqCSeq: 6 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 11 ......
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:53412;branch=z9hG4bK-323937-578fc8d6141edf477972319a2df16eeb;received=localIP;rport=53412
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=871832869
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as27145e38
Call-ID: c69dbe45ebc3fb4065161e16b9710452@localIP
CSeq: 6 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 731368999 731369000 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 18566 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
```

Am I calling it right or missing something for Acknowledgement?

Comment: Do you have javax.sip.AUTOMATIC_DIALOG_SUPPORT enabled?

Comment: No i have turned it off .

Comment: If it's off then you have to create the dialog yourself with this method https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/javadoc/javax/sip/SipProvider.html#getNewDialog(javax.sip.Transaction)

Comment: I turned it ON it works now :)